# Line Integral of Koch's Curve

Tags: calculus, integration, multivariable-calculus, greens-theorem

> Use Green’s Theorem to evaluate 
>   $$\int_C \langle \sin \sqrt{{1+x^3}},\ 7x \rangle \cdot d\textbf{r}$$
>   where $C$ is the boundary of the region $K(4)$. $K(3)$ is a triangle with $3 \cdot 4^2$ of length $\frac{1}{27}$. $K(4)$ is a Koch Snowflake, with $3 \cdot 4^3$ triangles of length $\frac{1}{81}$ added. It has dimension $\frac{\log(4)}{\log(3)}$.

First and foremost, we can calculate the curl of the vector field, which is just $7$. Then, we just have to find the area of $K(3)$ and multiply by $7$. However, I am having issues trying to find the area of this. Can anyone help?

Answer (score 0):

The Koch snowflake is an equilateral triangle with side length L

$A = \frac {\sqrt {3}}{4} L^2$

plus 3 triangles with side length $\frac {L}{3}$

$+ 3\frac {\sqrt {3}}{4} (\frac {L}{3})^2$

plus 12 triangles with side length $\frac {L}{9}$

$+ 12\frac {\sqrt {3}}{4} (\frac {L}{9})^2$

plus 48 triangles with side length $\frac {L}{27}$

$+ 48\frac {\sqrt {3}}{4} (\frac {L}{27})^2$

It grows regularly after this.

$\frac {\sqrt {3}}{4} L^2(1 + \frac 13\sum_\limits{n=0}^{\infty} (\frac {4}{9})^n)$

And that is a geometric series...

$\frac {\sqrt {3}}{4} L^2(1 + \frac 13 \frac {1}{1-\frac 49})$

Actually re-reading the problem, it looks like this one is finite...

$\frac {\sqrt {3}}{4} L^2(1 + \frac 13\sum_\limits{n=0}^{3} (\frac {4}{9})^n)$

$\frac {\sqrt {3}}{4} L^2(1 + \frac 13 \frac {1-\frac {4}{9}^4}{1-\frac 49})$